How is the contraction for "one of" spelled?
What is the contraction spelled out for one of?


One-a the girls said no.
Onea the girls said no.
One-ah?


I'm writing a dialogue.

Of is traditionally represented by o' (as in o'clock).

In casual speech, one of the girls sounds like one a the girls. No need to re-spell.

@KateBunting which works great if you're trying to write early 20th century or earlier dialogue.  To my eye, at least, it looks totally wrong for modern speech, at least modern American speech.  But u generally find dialogue that departs too much from standard spelling in an attempt to convey authenticity to be too distracting to read -- and if it was written by someone with a significantly different accent from mine then I am liable to misread or misunderstand it.

For informal, especially less common, non-standard contractions, there is no written rule how you should spell them. There are only some conventions, and the unwritten rule is to spell it in such a way that the reader can understand exactly what's being said without too much trouble. Also, consistency definitely helps:

The correct use of contractions in literature, playwriting, screenwriting, and poetry is perfectly acceptable – as long as you’re consistent. Each sentence should feel part of the whole, so it makes sense to choose a style and stick with it. (Relay publishing)

The accepted traditional contraction of of is o', and it has passed even into formal writing as part of fixed expressions or names such as:

three o'clock, cat o' nine tails, jack-o'-lantern, will-o'-wisp, man o' war, run-o'-the-mill

but is seen as informal in

cup o' coffee. (Wikipedia)

But in spoken language of is more commonly contracted to a, like in cuppa, kinda, outta, lotta, sorta.
For one of the, the most common contraction is one a the with or without an apostrophe which is placed either before or after a.
Tvtropes quotes funny moments of the TV series Top Cat:

Dibble: Gambling again, huh?!
Top Cat: Oh, that's just a collection. One a' the girls in the office is gettin' married. (ep. 30)

A tweet says:

Ol Erik's gotta be one'a the worst managers in Premier League history.

Here is a quote from Throwback (Charles Lee · 2013), which uses a lot of contractions:

"Nah! 'Ere's some, but most of `em er north a here 'round Cushman, Cave City, an' Guion. 'Ere is one down at a bottom a 'is hill though. Foun' it years ago when one a the boys playin' 'round 'ere almost fell in it.

One a has been around for a while:

'trwan't much better than gitting in one's coffin than to git into one a them shelves, but, after you got in, it was jest as well they was small, 'cause you hadn't fur to go when the ship got to kavaulting, like it did most all the time. (Electra: A Magazine of Pure Literature,1885)


I'd view one o' the, or either one o' ze or one o' da (epending upon intended pronunciation of the second consonant) as more readable than one a....

@supercat Agreed; in fact, in general I'd expect ‘o'’ to be pronounced pretty much the same as ‘a’ (both with a neutral vowel), making the latter mostly redundant anyway.

I think ‘cuppa’ is an outlier there; it may nominally stand for ‘cup of’, but I can only recall seeing it alone (“I'd love a cuppa!”), and would expect it to be spelled ‘cup of’ when followed by a drink name, however it was pronounced.

@gidds: I wouldn't say "cuppa" is an outlier, but rather that when the consonant is omitted from "of", the spelling varies depending upon whether it's stuck onto a word (e.g. "buncha", "lotta", or the afforementioned "cuppa") or stands alone.  It's rare for an "o" at the end of a word to be pronounced as a schwa, so using an "a" helps with pronunciation.  On the other hand, "a" as a standalone word has a meaning completely distinct from "of".

@supercat An outlier in the sense that you would use ‘cuppa’ on its own, but probably not as a modifier (spelling that ‘cup of [something]’ instead); conversely, you wouldn't usually use ‘kinda’, ‘outta’, ‘lotta’, or ‘sorta’ on their own, and you would use them as modifiers: ‘kinda [something]’, ‘outta [something]’, ‘lotta [something]’, and ‘sorta [something]’.

Is "cuppa" unique?  Sorta.  Well, not exactly unique.

If you actually pronounce the "f", the contraction would probably be written as "one'v", similar to the way contractions of "have" are written, e.g. "should've" and "would've".

The suggestion one've the girls … in its full form would be one have the girls … I think a lot of people would read it this way. Maybe the "e" should  be omitted: One'v the girls …

You're probably right, I've updated the answer.

If you write of contracted here, then to be consistent you should write it nearly always contracted. "The crux'v the matter", "A piece'v cake". I hope it's clear that I am not recommending this practice! (And in any case, the OP's question makes it clear that the "f" is not pronounced.)

@TonyK People don't always merge these words when speaking. And in many cases they leave out the "f" sound, e.g. "piece-a cake"

Usually, apostrophes represent omitted letters, but here the 'v' is a new introduction which is not in the original uncontracted spelling. Is there any example of this being used? I did some Google searches for "one'v" and "one'v the" but at least the first several pages don't have any relevant results.

usually true, but in contractions like these you go by the sound, not the original spelling. "one'f" looks like it would be pronounced with an unvoiced "f" sound.

Barmar, "one'v" is monstrous! And it's pronounced exactly the same as "one of". So why suggest it? There is simply no need for it.

Wonna
This extract is from Beulah Hill By William Heffernan (pub 2001) and is written in eye-dialect and shows the contraction in AE for “one of”:

“You sure to be outta work, you keep chasin' after wonna the few fool Republicans we got in this here town. Not that I wouldn’t like seen’ a Republican in jail, mind you.”


Wonna bet? :--)

@tchrist Isn't that usually written as "wanna"?

I suggest "wunna" instrad of "wonna", which is more like "want to" as noted by @tchist.
